Android Beacon Library: How to scan for iBeacon in background without using inner JobScheduler mechanism? (I use own WorkManager instead)
For about a week I've been trying to implement an iBeacon chip-scanning feature in the background using WorkManager (periodic, every 15 minutes).
I implemented iBeacon chip scanning when the app is opened (foreground) and when it’s closed (in the background using WorkManager).
When the app is opened (foreground), the chip is scanned quickly, approximately within 100-1000 milliseconds.
But, when the app is closed the scanning behaves inconsistently. Sometimes (rarely) it might scan the chip quite fast, in 500-1000 milliseconds, but most of the time it takes more than 30-60 seconds (which is quite long) or may not detect the chip at all, even though the chip is always on.
Here’s the Util code I implemented for scanning:
object BeaconScanUtil {
    private lateinit var applicationContext: Context
    private val uuid = Identifier.parse("39ED98FF-2900-441A-802F-9C398FC199D2")
    private var region = Region("all-beacons", uuid, null, null)
    
    var currentBluetoothId: Int? = null

    private val rangingObserver by lazy {
        Observer<Collection<Beacon>> { beacons ->
            val beacon = beacons.firstOrNull()
            if (beacon != null) {
                val majorId = beacon.id2.toInt()
                currentBluetoothId = majorId

                stopScanning()
            }
        }
    }

    // I call this method from the Application.onCreate()
    fun initialize(context: Context) {
        applicationContext = context.applicationContext
        BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(applicationContext).apply {
            // Since we don't care about AltBeacon, we clear it from the defaults
            beaconParsers.clear()

            val parser = BeaconParser().apply {
                // Layout for iBeacon
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")
                setHardwareAssistManufacturerCodes(arrayOf(0x004c).toIntArray())
            }
            beaconParsers.add(parser)

            setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)

            getRegionViewModel(region).rangedBeacons.observeForever(rangingObserver)
        }
    }

    suspend fun scanForBeacons(maxDurationMs: Long, backgroundMode: Boolean): BeaconScanResult? {
        val minDurationMs = 500L // 0.5s
        val intervalMs = 100L // 0.1s
        var durationMs = 0L

        startScanning(backgroundMode)

        try {
            while (durationMs < maxDurationMs) {
                if (durationMs >= minDurationMs) {
                    val currentBluetoothId = currentBluetoothId
                    if (currentBluetoothId != null) {
                        return BeaconScanResult(currentBluetoothId, durationMs)
                    }
                }

                durationMs += intervalMs
                delay(intervalMs)
            }
            val currentBluetoothId = currentBluetoothId
            return if (currentBluetoothId != null) {
                BeaconScanResult(currentBluetoothId, durationMs)
            } else {
                null
            }
        } finally {
            stopScanning()
        }
    }

    private fun startScanning(backgroundMode: Boolean) {
        resetBeaconsInfo()
        val beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(applicationContext)
        beaconManager.setBackgroundModeInternal(backgroundMode)
        beaconManager.startRangingBeacons(region)
    }

    private fun stopScanning() {
        val beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(applicationContext)
        beaconManager.stopRangingBeacons(region)
    }

    private fun resetBeaconsInfo() {
        currentBluetoothId = null
    }
}

data class BeaconScanResult(val bluetoothId: Int, val timeSpentOnScanMs: Long)

Here is the code for scanning the chip in background using WorkManager:
class ScanBeaconWorker(
    context: Context,
    param: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, param) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val hasAllConditionsToScanForBeacon = ... 

            if (!hasAllConditionsToScanForBeacon) {
                return@withContext Result.failure()
            }

            val timeToFindBeacon = BeaconScanUtil.scanForBeacons(
                maxDurationMs = 60_000L, 
                backgroundMode = true
            )
            showAutoCheckInCheckInNotification(
                context = applicationContext,
                title = "Time: ${timeToFindBeacon?.timeSpentOnScanMs ?: 60_000}",
                description = "Beacon ID: ${timeToFindBeacon?.bluetoothId}"
            )

            return@withContext Result.success()
        }
    }

    private fun showAutoCheckInCheckInNotification(
        context: Context,
        title: String,
        description: String,
    ) {
        // show notification
    }
}


Could you, please, help me understand what might be wrong with this code?

Does startRangingBeacons(region) work in the background? Or should I use startMonitoring(region) instead? (I need major beacon value)

Or could you, please, provide the proper code sample to scan for beacons without using the inner JobScadular mechanism? (since I use custom WorkManager instead to execute the scanning in the background)

Or should I use another approach to scan for beacons in the background?


Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance!
I use this library:
https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html

You can disable the Android Beacon Library's internal usage of the Android Job Scheduler by calling:
beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)
When disabled, the library uses a regular Android service to handle the scanning.  This should be allowed by the OS when the work manager is allowed to be active.
Both ranging and monitoring work fine in the background.
The code shown turns the library background mode on and off by calling private internal methods of the library which is not recommended and may be causing problems.  The library manages background mode internally and adjusts scanning as needed by the OS based on detected foreground/background state.  By default, the library also adjusts scanning to happen as most every 5 minutes in the background.
If you want direct control over scan periods so scanning happens right away on your command, simply adust the scan period and between scan period of the library.  The scan period defines how long the library spends scanning in milliseconds before pausing scans to save battery.  Long between scan periods (30000ms default in background) will save battery, but delay detections.  You may want to set this to 0 if the work manager code already limits scans programmatically:
// Defaults shown below
beaconManager.setScanPeriod(1100) / ms
beaconManager.setBetweenScanPeriod(0) / ms
// These are changes NOT defaults
beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100) / ms
beaconManager.setBackgroundBerweenScanPeriod(0) / ms
Call the above code before starting ranging or monitoring.  Changing these dynamically after ranging and monitoring are already started will have undefined effects.
Understand that the library is designed to be most easily used for programs that tell it to start looking for beacons by starting ranging or monitoring and just leave it on.  If you want to use it to start and stop dynamically in your own code, that is certainly allowed, but it makes it less easy to use.

Great, it's a pleasure to get an answer from the author of the library! In general, my goal is to avoid extra scanning for beacons in the background. So I start the worker in the background every 15 minutes, and in this worker, I check if it's a weekend day (and some other checks). And if it is then I scan for beacons for about 6-10 seconds to get a major ID to use it for further code. Do you think Android Beacon Library has enough tools to do this without creating own WorkManager or own JobScheduler? Thank you very much in advance!
